# What equation would you use to solve this cyclist problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*In an 80 mile relay race, two cyclists exchange at the mid-point of the race. The winning cyclist crossed the finish line at 3 hours and 36 minutes. What was the speed of each cyclist if the losing cyclist was 5 mph slower than the winning one?*

I thought that maybe finding the LCM would work but since I don't know the losing cyclist's time, that's not an option. Should I be using a velocity formula?

(The answer is 25 miles per hour for the winning one and 20 miles per hour for the losing one but I'm not sure how to get there.)

Comment: I assume the race is 80 miles? Take the speed of cyclist 2 to be $x$ mph. Cyclist 1 then had a speed of $x+5$ mph. Can you find a formula in terms of $x$ how long each cyclist took to cycle 40 miles? (Losing team does not matter in this problem.)

Comment: 80 km = 49.71 miles

Comment: The answer you gave ($20$ and $25$ mph) is the correct answer if the race was 80 miles, and not 80 kilometres. Either the numbers are all in miles and mph, or they are all in km and kph, because there is no unit conversion needed used to arrive at the given answer.

Comment: I'm perplexed by the use of "winning" and "losing" here. If these two cyclists make an exchange at the midpoint in a relay race, they are presumably on the same team. One of them might be *faster* and the other *slower*, but in what sense does one of them win and the other lose?

Answer (score 1):

If the speed of the slower cyclist is $x$ kh/h

the total time taken by both the cyclist together

$$\dfrac{40}x+\dfrac{40}{x+5}=\dfrac{36}{60}+3$$

Comment: Where did the 40 comes from?

Comment: @orangebull That's the length of half the race, which is how far they each cycle.

Comment: I see. Is there a specific velocity formula you used to construct this equation?

Comment: Also, they both finished the race at 80 miles, so I'm not sure why you used the mid-point of 40 miles in this formula...